# R: Filling timeseries values but only within last 12 months

Tags: r, time-series

How can we fill/forward pad a time series in R but only if the last value is within the last 12 months/observations otherwise NA?

Sample data: Variable is the original and desired is the desired outcome.
We observe NAs from June 2016 but we will forward pad. I only want to do this for 12 months so as soon as we reach July 2017 the last non-NA is too long a go and should be NA. That's why something like fill() alone will not do

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXfDr.png)

minimum working example: Consider the below using max gap and na.locf

```
x = c(NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,5,6,7,NA,NA,NA)
zoo::na.locf(x,  maxgap = 2, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Instead of not filling anything when number of NAs> max gap I would like the below output:
NA,1,2,3,3,3,5,6,7,7,7,NA. So if I specify gap =2 I would want at most two values filled and any more NAs should stay NA

Comment: What does _fill/forward pad a time series_ means? Can you add an example of your desired outcome so we can help better?

Comment: he probably have missing dates in time series data and want to insert dates to create uniform time steps. But last 12 months from which date?

Comment: The data already has uniform time steps. I want to fill the NAs, but if the last available value is longer than 12 months ago set NA instead

Comment: @Kathi Please add some sample data so that people can help you easily. You should expect others to spent time on creating sample data for you. Please note `image` doesnt help as it will require someone to typing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
my_fill <- function(x,maxgap=2){
  y<-x
  counter<-0
  for(i in 2:length(y)){
    if(is.na(y[i] & counter<maxgap)){
      y[i]<-y[i-1]
      counter<-counter+1
    }else{
      counter<-0
    }
  }
  return(y)
}

x = c(NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,5,6,7,NA,NA,NA)
my_fill(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `tidyr::fill`. The approach is to create columns as `desired` and `TempDate` in such a way that `desired` will have same value as `variable` but rows with `""` (blank) value for `variable` will have `desired` as `NA`. Similarly `TempDate` will have same value as `date` but  it will have  `NA` for rows where `variable` got `""` values.

`fill` both `desired` and `TempDate` and replace `desired` to `NA` where `TempDate` is older by more than 12 months than `date`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(TempDate = as.Date(ifelse(variable=="", NA, date),origin = "1970-01-01"),
              desired = ifelse(variable=="",NA, variable)) %>%
  fill(desired, TempDate) %>%
  mutate(desired = ifelse(date > (TempDate +months(12)), NA, desired)) %>%
  select(-TempDate)

#          date variable desired
# 1  2016-01-01        1       1
# 2  2016-02-01        2       2
# 3  2016-03-01        3       3
# 4  2016-04-01        3       3
# 5  2016-05-01        3       3
# 6  2016-06-01       33      33
# 7  2016-07-01               33
# 8  2016-08-01               33
# 9  2016-09-01               33
# 10 2016-10-01               33
# 11 2016-11-01               33
# 12 2016-12-01               33
# 13 2017-01-01               33
# 14 2017-02-01               33
# 15 2017-03-01               33
# 16 2017-04-01               33
# 17 2017-05-01               33
# 18 2017-06-01               33
# 19 2017-07-01             <NA>
# 20 2017-08-01             <NA>
# 21 2017-09-01       34      34
# 22 2017-10-01               34
```

**Data:** Based on image shared by OP

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2017-10-01"), by="month"),
           variable = c(1,2,3,3,3,33,rep("",14),34,""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
#          date variable
# 1  2016-01-01        1
# 2  2016-02-01        2
# 3  2016-03-01        3
# 4  2016-04-01        3
# 5  2016-05-01        3
# 6  2016-06-01       33
# 7  2016-07-01         
# 8  2016-08-01         
# 9  2016-09-01         
# 10 2016-10-01         
# 11 2016-11-01         
# 12 2016-12-01         
# 13 2017-01-01         
# 14 2017-02-01         
# 15 2017-03-01         
# 16 2017-04-01         
# 17 2017-05-01         
# 18 2017-06-01         
# 19 2017-07-01         
# 20 2017-08-01         
# 21 2017-09-01       34
# 22 2017-10-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using base R.  `k` specifies the gap size.  `x` is defined in the minimum working example in the question.

`cumsum(!is.na(x))` produces a grouping vector in which each non-NA followed by any NAs are regarded as one group.  Then for each such group replace the first k+1 elements (or the number of elements in the group if less) with the first element of the group leaving the remaining elements as NA.

```
k <- 2
ave(x, cumsum(!is.na(x)), FUN = function(x) replace(x, 1:min(length(x), k+1), x[1]))
## [1] NA  1  2  3  3  3  5  6  7  7  7 NA
```

Note that this idea is also used in this SO answer [Change maxgap for number of times a value is carried forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486104/change-maxgap-for-number-of-times-a-value-is-carried-forward/50496346#50496346) involving data.table.